# Legendre functions as solution of differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In Abramowitz/Stegun you read that

$$Q_s(x) := \int_{0}^\infty  ( x  + \sqrt{x^2-1}  \cosh t )^{-s} dt, \quad x > 1, \Re(s)>0$$

is a solution to the differential equation
$$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+s(s-1)y=0.$$

How do you prove that? I differentiated under the integral sign and wrote down $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+s(s-1)y$ with $Q_s$ for $y$ but couldn't see how it vanishs. Do you need to use some fancy functional equations of $\cosh$ to obtain the result?

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete answer:

---

Note that your Dif-EQ
$$(1-z^2)\,y'' -2zy' + s(s+1)y = 0 \tag{1}$$
Is a special case of Legendre Equation, which we can solve by transforming it into a sub-case of  the Hypergometric Dif-Eq,
$$z(1-z)y'' + \left[c-(a+b+1)z \right] y' - ab\,y = 0$$
which can be solve completely via the Hypergeometric function $_2F_1$, yielding the following solution to $(1)$:
$$y(z)=c_1P_s(z)+c_2Q_s(z)$$
Concerning ourselves with the function $P_s(z)$, (which is simpler to express but very similar) we get the definition
$$P_s(z) = {_2}F_1\left(-s,s+1;1;\frac{1-z}{z}\right)$$
Now you will need to apply the right integral identity. As I mentioned in a deleted comment, one can apply the Barnes Integral formula here with a lot of brute force, but I think there should be a cleaner method.